# Detect which checkbox was clicked from a CheckBoxMultipleChoice in Apache Wicket

Tags: checkbox, wicket

I am facing a problem with a CheckBoxMultipleChoice in Wicket.

Let's assume the optiones are:

```
[] White
[] Black 
[] Blue 
[] Yellow 
[] Red 
[] None of the above
```

What I have to do, is to notice when "None of the above" is clicked and then uncheck the rest of the choices. And if "None of the above" is selected and the user clicks on any other option, i.e. "Red", then "None of the above" must be unchecked.

I can detect the values when the checkbox group changes, but I can't say which one was the exact option that was clicked, so I can see, for example, that the user chose "Red" and "None of the above" but I can not say if he just clicked in "Red" or in "None of the above", so I don't know what do if I have to uncheck "Red" or "None of the above"...

Comment: You could try keeping list of previous choices and compare with current. It's not cleanest, but will most likely work.

Comment: Yes, I had thought of that, but I was looking for a cleaner solution. Thanks.

Comment: How about splitting this into a CheckBoxMultipleChoice for the option and a single Checkbox for 'none' and have this one reset the model of the multiple choice one?

Comment: Well, yes, I have already thought of that... maybe it is the best possible solution. But I really thought it could be in any way possible to detect which one of the checkboxes was clicked... I suppose it could be "styled" so they really look as one single component, that is what I want. Hum.

Comment: Have you tried to use javascript to check/uncheck the boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really determine which checkbox was clicked *first* without catching the event in Javascript. What you're trying do is basically the same as a "select all" checkbox, except inverted in the case where you select it (everything else gets deselected) and I'm assuming just doing nothing in case it gets deselected.

Have a look at how Wicket's CheckboxMultipleChoiceSelector does it (particularly what AbstractCheckSelector and CheckboxSelector.js do). The code there adds click handlers to all the checkboxes plus the "select all" checkbox. The ones on the regular checkboxes update the "select all" and vice versa. You basically need the same, except you invert the effects.